# How could I convert a for statement in DB2 to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, db2

I need to convert a for statement in DB2 to MYSQL but I have no clue so far. Could someone give me some hints or tell me how to write it in MYSQL?
The code below is a sample for statement I found in the IBM website.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE fullname CHAR(40);
  FOR v1 AS
      c1 CURSOR FOR
   SELECT firstname, midinit, lastname FROM employee
    DO
      SET fullname =
          lastname CONCAT ', '
                   CONCAT firstname
                   CONCAT ' '
                   CONCAT midinit;
      INSERT INTO TNAMES VALUES ( fullname );
  END FOR; 
END;
```

Comment: That seems an overly complex way to generate a full name in any version of sql   , surely an insert...select would do?

Comment: But MYSQL seems doesn't have FOR statement. If I just copy the sample code in MYSQL workbench it will give me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select title,firstname,middlename,lastname from awperson limit 10;
+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
| title | firstname | middlename | lastname   |
+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
|       | Ken       | J          | Sánchez    |
|       | Terri     | Lee        | Duffy      |
|       | Roberto   |            | Tamburello |
|       | Rob       |            | Walters    |
| Ms.   | Gail      | A          | Erickson   |
| Mr.   | Jossef    | H          | Goldberg   |
|       | Dylan     | A          | Miller     |
|       | Diane     | L          | Margheim   |
|       | Gigi      | N          | Matthew    |
|       | Michael   |            | Raheem     |
+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t (fullname varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t(fullname)
    -> select trim(concat(ifnull(title,''),' ',ifnull(firstname,''),' ',ifnull(middlename,''),' ',ifnull(lastname,'')))
    -> from awperson
    -> limit 10;
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+-----------------------+
| fullname              |
+-----------------------+
| Ken J Sánchez         |
| Terri Lee Duffy       |
| Roberto  Tamburello   |
| Rob  Walters          |
| Ms. Gail A Erickson   |
| Mr. Jossef H Goldberg |
| Dylan A Miller        |
| Diane L Margheim      |
| Gigi N Matthew        |
| Michael  Raheem       |
+-----------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is it possible that I could still use cursor to do it?

Comment: Cursors should only be used when set operations won't do, any reason why you wish to use cursor?

Comment: Yes I need to use SET after the for loop. I I'm wondering how to write for statement of cursor in MYSQL.

Comment: You should read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html write some code the mysql way and if you get into difficulty post your code for assistance.